LNK2019 Error After Removing Linked Projects in Visual Studio 2022
I'm facing an issue where I'm getting LNK2019 errors in Visual Studio 2022 after removing linked projects from my solution. The errors are related to references from the removed projects, indicating that the linker is unable to find the definitions for certain symbols. This situation has arisen despite the removal of the projects, suggesting that there might be lingering references or configurations that still point to the old projects.
I've tried several approaches to resolve this issue, including:
Checking the project's external dependencies in the Solution Explorer to ensure that there are no lingering references to the removed projects.
Verifying that the .vcxproj file does not contain any references to the removed projects.
Ensuring that the project-to-project references are correctly set up, as Visual Studio requires a project-to-project reference for dependencies to be correctly resolved during the build process.
Despite these efforts, the LNK2019 errors persist. The errors specifically mention unresolved external symbols, which suggests that the linker is unable to find the definitions for these symbols.
Given the complexity of the issue, I'm seeking advice on how to fully resolve these LNK2019 errors. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding how to completely remove references to removed projects and ensure that the linker correctly resolves all dependencies. Any guidance or suggestions on best practices for managing project dependencies and resolving LNK2019 errors in Visual Studio 2022 would be greatly appreciated.

Look at what symbol is missing. Figure out what library that symbol belongs to. Evaluate if that library is still needed with your project or not. If it is not needed remove the "Additional Include Directories" setting that contains the folder that is the headers for that library and do a clean build possibly manually deleting the Debug and the Release folder completly. Also make sure that this library is not a dependency of any other external or internal library you use in your project.

Find the function mentioned in the lnk2019 error and link to the lib where the function is located.

@MinxinYu-MSFT I deleted the library, but I still see the references

Did you link the needed library? suggesting that there might be lingering references or configurations that still point to the old projects. No. It is not right.  See Possible causes.

I was only deleting projects instead of the whole project solution, I created a solution first before creating the projects. Deleting the lines referencing deleted folders in a solution and .vs folder helped. Thank you all

I was only deleting projects instead of the whole project solution, I created a solution first before creating the projects. Deleting the lines referencing deleted folders in a solution file and .vs folder helped. Thank you all

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
